# Live audio processing using c++ (standard or external libs 'ue4')

Tags: signal-processing

My goal is to get audio from the input of another device (either connected to computer throught aux or audio interface threw rca or coaxil(from an external device playing audio live) adapters to line or something) and let a certain property (gain or volume, probably just volume) drive the animation of a 3d model (The more the volume increases the model moves along a directional axis 'either procedraly animated or let it drive a pre made animation) preferably all in unreal engine because it already has a realtime graphics engine so no need to worry about the graphics just how would I go about getting the signal (which libraries should I look into) and how would I let the data drive the animation (not specific code that would work specifically in unreal just broad methodology)

Thanks a bunch